# How to set the "Show homepage by default for this folder" check box in the "Home Page" tab inside Properties option of "Outlook Data File"?

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I am using .Net c#.
I would like to set the "Show homepage by default for this folder" check box in the "Home Page" tab of the "Data File Properties" for an Outlook data file programmatically.
The data file is set as the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `MAPIFolder.WebViewURL` to the web page address and `MAPIFolder.WebViewOn` property to true. In case of the default store, the root folder can be assumed to be the Parent (`MAPIFolder.Parent`) of the Inbox folder (`Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)).`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Previously, I used the registry values to load and change the view. But I had problems with it.